# Microsoft Word 2007 Show/ hide table via dropdown

Tags: vba, ms-word

I got a problem where I could not find an answer. I want to show / hide tables in Word 2007. If a user clicks on a dropwdown list. Some tables should be hidden when printed and and some tables should be visible when printed. I guess I need to use VBA?

Scenario:

I got table: a, b ,c, d

When a user selects: b,d

Table a,c and should be hidden when printed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found [this](http://computer-programming-forum.com/1-vba/c499073e6801ec48.htm) on first google search.

resulting code:

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Range.Font.Hidden = True
ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Range.Font.Hidden = True
```

and yes you will have to use vba...
i am not sure if the collection Table is 0-Based or 1-based, you just need to look a bit

Comment: Well, and how do I give the table a name? (Tried to set a reference,tablea, but if I use it in VBA it does not exist...)

Comment: you don't need to. the tables automatically get numbers assigned.the numbers are correspondent to the timeline of adding the tables